# Android - Service - onDestroy() method not called when using Force Stop

Tags: android

When I stop a service using the stop button under the Running Services tab, the method onDestroy() is called.

But when I force stop the application, onDestroy() is never called.

Any explainations about this?

or maybe a solution to fire onDestroy() when force-stopped?

Answer (score 5):

When your force stop an app, exactly that happens - It is Force Stopped. No warning, no callbacks, just stopped. The entire process is killed, and none of the running components (Activities, Services etc) are given any warning.

There is absolutely **no** guarantee that `onDestroy()` will be called. Move any application critical code into `onPause()`, which is called under most circumstances.

Comment: Good answer.  However, the question is specifically about Services, which don't pause or have an onPause() method.  Compared to other components, Services don't have much of a lifecycle.  If there's something important that needs to be done at the end, maybe the service could be written to save as it works and continue where it left off if/when it's restarted.  Or, better yet, avoid having users kill your service by being "well behaved" and as short-running as possible.  :)

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html):

> Once the activity is created, `onPause()` is the last method that's guaranteed to be called before the process can be killed... `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` might not be called. Therefore, you should use `onPause()` to write crucial persistent data (such as user edits) to storage.

To reiterate this point, Force Stop isn't intended to be graceful and exit the app in a caring manner. If you have critical code that must be run each time app finishes you need to run it in `onPause()`.

Comment: What about the case where you use BIND_AUTO_CREATE to start a service in the Activity's onCreate() method and unbind from it in onDestroy()? If the activity is prematurely killed and onDestroy() never called, the service continues running.

Comment: I'm not sure what your trying to do, but it's possible the garbage collector might recognize this service is orphaned and obliterate it in a few minutes.

Comment: This is the documentation for an Activity - the OP is concerning Service.

Comment: Services do not have onPause() method. Please read the question again.

Comment: Answer doesn't provide the relevant information asked in the question. Question is in context of service and the documentation link that is given is for Activity. Service doesn;t have pause and stop states.

Answer (score 1):

When the application gets force stop, Process.killProcess() is called but not onDestroy() function. Go through this link. You will get some idea.
[Android force Stop callback to application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160897/android-force-stop-callback-to-application)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have code that you want to execute in `onDestroy()` referring to your line:

> "or maybe a solution to fire onDestroy() when force-stopped?"

The `Service` method [public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved%28android.content.Intent%29) is what you are looking for, it will be called when the app is force-stopped.

Comment: don't think that's true. onTaskRemoved() is not guaranteed to be called if you force stop the app.

Comment: onTaskRemoved() in service is called when your app is killed by swiping it from recent apps

Comment: Answer from @chetna is correct. This callback only fired when user swipe-to-close your app or it means close the app from task queue/recent task. It wont fire when the app being force-stop.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but I was having the same issue and in my case I was using a **binding service**, so even after called `stopSelf()` Android does not call `onDestroy()` method, in order to force it I need to call `unbindService()` first