# How to get Callback when app is force stopped

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

My app records audio using [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html)  API in the foreground or backgroud (when app is minimized) , but the audio file gets corrupted when the user force stop the application from application manager.

I have managed to stop recorder and update the audio header in other scenarios. but the app doesn't get any callbacks when it is force stopped.

How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11161408/931982)

> Force stopping the app will kill the entire process (i.e. with
>   Process.killProcess(int pid)). All resources associated with the
>   application will be removed and freed by the kernel. So no, there is
>   no way that you can intercept this action

So better use error handling In the critical sections of your code to detect the crashes.

Comment: i am using UncaughtExceptionHandler to catch the exception for error reporting when app crashes, but when the app force stops i am not able to do anything, AudioRecord doesnt have methods to listen to any errors.

Comment: did you figure out where the problem is

Comment: i don't have any solution to handle this situation, the audio gets corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can not do this.
Reason is that by force closing the app system is killing the process and there is no more code in memory to handle this.

A workaround would be to register for app crash intents inside your manifest and declare this Receiver to be ran in another process by adding android:process="com.test.process". You could start a service in this receiver and do what you want. Problem with this approach would be that you don't get access to original application memory but there is some data about the app that force closed inside Intent extras.