# Unity Android task kill did not trigger OnApplicationQuit nor OnDestroy

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

As title, when killing app in Android using the "Running Apps", OnApplicationQuit didn't trigger as expected.

Is there any workaround for this issue ?

Comment: You should look at this answer: [Android force Stop callback to application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160897/android-force-stop-callback-to-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ramazan linked when you kill app on running apps, the kernel destroy the app and it there is not time to unity call `OnApplicationQuit`

Don't forget when you open another app sometimes your app is just **paused** and it is not **destroyed**.

Take a look on this android docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Thanks, nice to know this, there are ApplicationFocus and ApplicationPause event called when the app lost focus. Will be create some workaround using these.