# How to cancel ongoing notification when app is killed in Oreo?

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, notificationmanager

I'm facing issue in cancelling ongoing notification from notification bar. It's working perfectly on previous versions of android using `onTaskremoved()` in **Service**,but not in ***Oreo***. *I just need to cancel notification when app is force closed from recent apps.*
Please let me know if any one have solution for this.
Previous versions

Comment: I just need to cancel notification when app is cleared from OS. Do you mean clear from Recent Apps?

Comment: Yes. From recent apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If you force close your app, onDestroy will not be called and you have no option to intercept this action.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6553967/7360848) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11161408/7360848) are two references about it, you can find much more

....................

Add Those line inside in you service

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopForeground(true);

}
```

Comment: `onDestroy()` is not called when force close the app.

Comment: you updated you question. There was no mention of force close previously. If you force close your app, `onDestroy` will not be called and you have no option to intercept this action

Comment: understood :). thanks for the response. if you have an answer for this, pls share it